# VoiceOver with UISegmentedControl in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, accessibility, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add VoiceOver to a Segmented Control but the Apple example code does not work with Swift 3:

The Objective C code:

```
NSString *title = @”∫”;
title.accessibilityLabel = @”Integral”;
[segmentedControl insertedSegmentedWithTitle:title];
```

does not work with Swift like this:

```
var title: NSString = "∫"
title.accessibilityLabel = "Integral"
segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: 0, animated: false)
```

Swift will only accept a String but I need to add an NSString since it has the VoiceOver attributes.

Can any help with this?

Is there a better approach for adding accessibility or VoiceOver to a segmented control?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Swift will also accept NSString. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Worst case, you can walk over subviews and set accessibility labels manually.

Comment: Teja, the swift version of insertSegment(withTitle is type specific for a String only and will not accept an NSString.

Comment: Andy, seems like alot of work for something that should 'work out of the box'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with Andy's comment I coded:

```
    segmentedControl.subviews[0].accessibilityLabel = "Seg 2";
    segmentedControl.subviews[1].accessibilityLabel = "Seg 1";
    segmentedControl.subviews[2].accessibilityLabel = "Seg 0";
```

Not the best, note subviews are reverse to appearance, but appears to be the only way at this time.

Greg

Comment: RADAR filed: 28355285 VoiceOver with UISegmentedControl broken in Swift 3